# How to get the timestamp + X minutes with DateTime and DateInterval

Tags: php

I want to get the timestamp in 15 minutes from now.

I don't want to use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php), I want to use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

I'm doing:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$in_15_m = $now->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));

echo 'Now:' . $now->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
echo 'In 15 min': . $in_15_m->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

But both printed lines contain the same date.

**How can I achieve this?**

The arguments for DateInterval aren't really clear in the docs, though I think I am using it the correct way.

Thanks.

Comment: Note you don't need DateInterval, as DateTime (like strtotime()) takes relative phrases as an argument, so you can just do something like `new DateTime('+15 minutes');`

Comment: [The docs for `DateTime::add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) have the important part - the method *modifies* the object, rather than just returning an updated copy. So `$now` and `$in_15_m` end up with the same values. [This question about DateTimeImmutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536245/datetimeimmutable-vs-datetime) might be useful.

Comment: @iainn Thanks for your help, I was focusing too much on one thing and boom, doing it wrong where I was thinking to be right.

Comment: Note that the default timezone for a DateTime is not necessarily UTC and that assumption, plus the hardcoding of `Z` as the timezone in the output, is a recipe for trouble down the line. Use `$now = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('UTC'));` or `$now->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('UTC'))`.

Comment: @Sammitch - Hey, appreciate that insight. I am working on this within some specific given circumstances. That's why it is that weird. This is very useful information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DateTime::add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method modifies the `DateTime` object *in place*.  It *also* returns the modified object for use in method chaining, but the original object is still modified.

You can use [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.add.php) instead:

```
$now = new DateTimeImmutable('now');
$in_15_m = $now->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));
echo 'Now:' . $now->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
echo "\n+15m:" . $in_15_m->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

Or, alternatively, use two objects:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$in_15_m = (new DateTime('now'))->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));
echo 'Now:' . $now->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
echo "\n+15m:" . $in_15_m->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

Comment: You can also do `clone $now` instead of instantiating a new DateTime object.